# Go - Download S3 file under a prefix

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I am trying to download a file that is under a directory instead of directly in a bucket.

```golang
    file, err := os.Create("s3file.csv")
    downloader := s3manager.NewDownloader(session.New(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-east-1")}))
    numBytes, err := downloader.Download(file,
        &s3.GetObjectInput{
            Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
            Key:    aws.String(key),
        })
```

Bucket name - "myBucket"
Folder name - "myFolder"
file name - "myFile"

GetObjectInput doesn't accept Prefix as a parameter.
Specifying only bucket name without prefix is leading to Key not found error.
Tried setting "bucket" as following but got error

1. myBucket/myFolder
2. myBucket/myFolder/
3. myBucket&prefix=myFolder

> Error: Failed to download file SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
> status code: 403, request id: 647D920C72888888

Note: Downloading a file directly under the bucket is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Bucket` should always be the name of your bucket. `Key` is the full name (path) of the object, so in your case, that should be `myFolder/myFile`.