# Download only specific folder in S3 bucket using python boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

The link below shows how to download an entire S3 content. However, how does one get subfolder content. Suppose my S3 folder has the following emulated structure.

S3Folder/S1/file1.c

S3Folder/S1/file2.h

S3Folder/S1/file1.h

S3Folder/S2/file.exe

S3Folder/S2/resource.data

Suppose I am interested only in S2 folder. How do I isolate the keys in bucket list ?

[local backup of an S3 content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063474/downloading-the-files-from-s3-recursively-using-boto-python)

```
conn = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)

# go through the list of files
bucket_list = bucket.list()
for l in bucket_list:
  keyString = str(l.key)
  d = LOCAL_PATH + keyString
  try:
    l.get_contents_to_filename(d)
  except OSError:
    # check if dir exists
    if not os.path.exists(d):
      os.mkdir(d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download s3 objects by adding prefix of it in the key value.

So, according to your Question , you just need to add prefix '/S2' while downloading objects

FYI: [s3 download object](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file)  using boto3

For more check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41108412/go-download-s3-file-under-a-prefix)

Comment: in the parameter 'key' you need to add . I would recommend you to read documentation .

Comment: I need to only grab S2 subfolder content. Thus far, I grab everything in the bucket

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following:

```
import os
import boto3
s3_resource = boto3.resource("s3", region_name="us-east-1")

    def download_objects():
        root_dir = 'D:/' # local machine location
        s3_bucket_name = 'S3_Bucket_Name' #s3 bucket name
        s3_root_folder_prefix = 'sample' # bucket inside root folder
        s3_folder_list = ['s3_folder_1','s3_folder_2','s3_folder_3'] # root folder inside sub folders list

        my_bucket = self.s3_resource.Bucket(s3_bucket_name)
        for file in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=s3_root_folder_prefix):
            if any(s in file.key for s in s3_folder_list):
                try:
                    path, filename = os.path.split(file.key)
                    try:
                        os.makedirs(root_dir + path)
                    except Exception as err:
                        pass
                    my_bucket.download_file(file.key, root_dir + path + '/' + filename)
                except Exception as err:
                    print(err)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    download_objects()
```